# Drop constraint on a column without knowing constraint name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to drop a constraint on column in more than one database. I do not know exact name of the constraint on a column.

Is it possible to Drop a constraint without knowing its name.

Ex:
ALTER TABLE TempTable DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS ON Columnname

Comment: It is a good idea to name constraints explicitly when creating them, so that you can its name for future changes. This is especially important if you have multiple clients with their own database, so that you can automate changes using the same script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can retrieve constraint information from a table like this

```
select t.Name as TableName,
       ccd.Name as ColumnName_default_constraint,
       dc.Name as default_constraint,
       ccc.Name as ColumnName_check_constraint,
       cc.Name as check_constraint
from   sys.tables t
  inner join sys.default_constraints dc on t.object_id = dc.parent_object_id
  inner join sys.check_constraints cc on t.object_id = cc.parent_object_id
  inner join sys.columns ccd on dc.parent_object_id = ccd.object_id 
                          and ccd.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
  inner join sys.columns ccc on cc.parent_object_id = ccc.object_id 
                          and ccc.column_id = cc.parent_column_id
where t.Name = 'your table name'
order by t.Name
```

from this you can build scripts like this

```
select 'alter table ' + t.Name +' drop constraint ' + dc.Name,
       'alter table ' + t.Name +' drop constraint ' + cc.Name
from   sys.tables t
  inner join sys.default_constraints dc on t.object_id = dc.parent_object_id
  inner join sys.check_constraints cc on t.object_id = cc.parent_object_id
where t.Name = 'your table name'
order by t.Name
```

Comment: I edited my answer, the first version only showed default constraints, now also check constraints will show up

Comment: Table might have many constraints, I would like to get name of a constraint for particular column.

Comment: @Ask_SO I edited my answer, the first query will now also show the column name that the constraint is on